# Kubernetes StatefulSet - does not resatore data on pod restart

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes version - 1.8

1. Created statefulset for postgres database with pvc
2. Added some tables to database
3. Restarted pod by scaling statefulset to 0 and then again 1
4. Created tables in step # 2 are no longer available

Tried another scnario with steps on docker-for-desktop cluster k8s version 1.10

1. Created statefulset for postgres database with pvc
2. Added some tables to database
3. Restarted docker for desktop
4. Created tables in step # 2 are no longer available

k8s manifest

```
    apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-config
  labels:
    app: postgres
data:
  POSTGRES_DB: kong
  POSTGRES_USER: kong
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: kong
  PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/postgresql/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgres-pvc
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
  app: postgres
spec:
  ports:
  - name: pgql
    port: 5432
    targetPort: 5432
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: postgres
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2 #  for k8s versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2  and before 1.8.0 use extensions/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  serviceName: "postgres"
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:9.6
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-config
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgredb
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pvc
---
```

Comment: Consider adding the manifests that you used to create your environment. Without that, we don't have the minimal idea on what type of resources you are using _(e.g., the problem would be a `hostPath` Persistent Volume, which doesn't work when using multiple nodes...)_. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Added k8s manifest i am using

Comment: Are you using a single-node cluster (like Minikube), or a Kubernetes cluster with multiple nodes? If using multiple nodes, the problem is the `hostPath` volume that mounts directory from the host node’s filesystem into your Pod. When the pod is recreated, it may be scheduled in another node, causing the volume data loss. Try to recreate you steps, checking this time in what node the pod is being allocated with `kubectl get po -o wide`

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple nodes - the issue you see is totally expected. So if you want to use hostPath as a Persistent Volume in a multi-node cluster - you must use some shared filesystem like Glusterfs or Ceph and place your /mnt/postgresql/data folder onto that shared filesystem.

Comment: Well, as it is a guess, this should be a comment tip, not an definitive answer...  The `hostPath` concerns are even already stated in the comments for the question.